# Show an elliptic curve is a twist of another curve?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

> Let $E/k$ be an elliptic curve defined by the Weierstrass form
>   $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. Let $c$ be a nonzero square free element in $k$. Let
>   ${E_c}/k$ be a curve defined by $cy^2=x^3+ax+b$. Using a linear change
>   of variables in $\bar{k}$ (isomorphism over $\bar{k}$), show that
>   $E_c$ is a twist of $E$.

So I want to show that $E_c$ and $E$ are isomorphic over $\bar{k}$ but not isomorphic over $k$. I think the best way to do this is to show they have the same j-invariant. However, I'm not sure what change of variables to use to show that.

What's the best way to show $E_c$ is a twist of $E$?

Comment: Over $\overline{k}$, there is certainly going to be a square root of $c$, so you could consider $y\mapsto \sqrt{c} y$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by considering $y \rightarrow \sqrt{c}y$?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I mean is consider the change of variables $x' = x$ and $y' = \sqrt{c} y$. Now $E_c: (y')^2 = (x')^3 + ax' + b$ is in terms of $x'$ and $y'$. But the map $y \mapsto y'$ is just multiplication by a non-zero constant over $\overline{k}$ which should yield an isomorphism between the two curves. It might be the case that I am oversimplifying. But the idea here is that the two curves actually become isomorphic over $k' = k(\sqrt{2})$, and therefore over $\overline{k}$.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense, thank you. If you'd like to make that comment an answer I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your request, I am turning my comment into an answer:

Consider the change of variables
\begin{align*}
    x' & = x\\
    y' &= \sqrt{c}y
\end{align*}
Then in the new variables we have $E_c: (y')^2 = (x')^3 + ax' + b$. The map $y\mapsto y'$ is multiplication by a non-zero element of $\overline{k}$ which gives a $\overline{k}$ isomorphism between $E$ and $E_c$.

Note: This map is defined over $k(\sqrt{c})$; thus the two curves actually become isomorphic over a quadratic extension.